# TYPO3 tt_news : No code given

Tags: typo3

I just inherited this TYPO3 project and have a bunch of tasks to perform with it (adding this here, and that there, etc.) and I'm at the task "Add news to the front page" and "Add a RSS feed to the site"

Well, the `tt_news` extension is installed and I have created 1 test news. Now I added a page content plugin of type "News" and configured it from the best of my knowledge, following the outdated manual provided with the extension, saved the page, cleared the cache and refreshed the frontend page to see this :

[image]

...What does it mean and how do I make the extension work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit the content element containing tt_news extension and at the `Plugin` tab in select field `What to display` choose default view ie: `Standard list view (LIST)`

[image]

Also:

1. make sure that in Content Element's settings you choose correct
   folder with tt_news records in field `Other settings` > `Page(s)
   with tt_news records`
2. tt_news records are created by default with `Hidden` flag set to true, make sure that the checkbox is **unchecked**. (BTW this behaviour can be changed with `TCAdefaults.tt_news.hidden=0` in `PageTS` or `UserTS`)

Comment: Would you know, by any chance, why my only news is not showing in the list, on the frontend side?

Comment: @YanickRochon: (About FAQ) Because you can also set default view with TypoScript: `plugin.tt_news.code = LIST` and in such case option `Defined with TypoScript` will be valid, it's documented in http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/tt_news/3.0.1/view/1/4/ (Reference: code)

(About not showing news) : make sure that in Content Element's settings you choose correct folder with tt_news records in field `Other settings` > `Page(s) with tt_news records`

Comment: I have two news (set to category "News") associated with page called "Home" (ID=2) and I set the "PageId for single news display" and "Page(s) with tt_news records" to "Home" (save, clear cache, refresh frontent) and still do not get anything displayed in the news content.

Comment: @YanickRochon: tt_news records are created by default with `Hidden` flag set to true, make sure that the checkbox is **unchekced**

Comment: Yay! (dances around the computer chair)

Comment: Hahaha! Dancing developers - let it be :D Good luck with next T3 issues, most of them can be figured out with docs and community although sometimes just a time-eaters.